# Confusing syntax found in malware

Tags: binary-analysis

I am confused by what the following command is doing:

```
00401234  mov     dword [esp+0x35], sub_408678
```

For context, I'm reversing a piece of malware and am using Binary Ninja, which to my knowledge typically uses the following syntax for low level IL commands:

```
mov    dest, src
```

Is the first command executing the subroutine specified in the `src` parameter (sub_408678) and storing the result of that command in [esp + 35]? Or just moving the address for later use? I have never seen this syntax before, I'm wondering if someone else has seen a program do this / can tell me what the purpose of writing it this way is. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

src sub_408678 is probably a label given by your tool to the address 408678

[esp+0x35] the destination is a pointer to a 32 bit value

it can take anything from 0x0 to 0xffffffff

so after executing this instruction `00401234  mov     dword [esp+0x35], sub_408678` [esp+0x35 will point to 0x408678

in high level construct this will be

```
<sometype *>foo ; // here sometype can be int,long,in your cse function_ptr etc 
foo = &blah
```

a sample code and disassembly

```
unsigned long global = 0xdeadbeef;
int main (void) {
    unsigned long *foo;
    foo = &global;
    return *foo;
}
```

disassembly

```
:\>cdb -c "uf ptr!main;q" ptr.exe | awk "/Reading/,/quit/"
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'uf ptr!main;q'
ptr!main:
01381000 55              push    ebp
01381001 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
01381003 51              push    ecx
01381004 c745fc00903c01  mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],offset ptr!global (013c9000) <<<<<<<
0138100b 8b45fc          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]
0138100e 8b00            mov     eax,dword ptr [eax]
01381010 8be5            mov     esp,ebp
01381012 5d              pop     ebp
01381013 c3              ret
quit:
```